# Expand White Noise and Brownian Motion in Haar basis: which version of Haar basis?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, brownian-motion

Start with the Haar basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, namely, the functions
$$
\chi(t-k) \text { and } 2^{j / 2} h\left(2^j t-k\right), j \geq 0, k \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad \quad \quad (1)
$$
where $\chi(t)$ is the indicator function of $[0,1]$ and where $h(t)=1$ on $[0,1 / 2), h(t)=-1$ on $[1 / 2,1)$ and $h(t)=0$ outside $[0,1)$. Observe that $\left\{\chi(t), 2^{j / 2} h\left(2^j t\right), j \geq 0\right\}$ is the Haar basis for $L^2[0,1]$ and the index $k$ translates this basis to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

This [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01261639) by Meyer, Sellan, and Taqqu "Wavelets, generalized white noise and fractional integration: the synthesis of fractional Brownian motion" provide an expansion of Gaussian white noise $Z(t)$ and Brownian motion $B(t)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ in this basis.

However, as I understand (1) is not the only way to express the Haar basis. For example in [this link](https://users.math.yale.edu/pub/wavelets/software/xwpl/html/manual/node28.html) the Haar wavelet is defined as:
$$
h(x)= \begin{cases}1 & 0<x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ -1 & \frac{1}{2}<x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x \leq 0 \text { or } 1<x\end{cases}
$$
and the Haar basis consists of the functions
$$
h_k^j(x)=2^{j / 2} h\left(2^j x-k\right) \quad \begin{gathered}
j=0, \pm 1, \pm 2 \ldots \\
k=0, \pm, \pm 2 \ldots
\end{gathered} \quad \quad \quad (2)
$$
Then, in the latter the term $\chi(t-k)$ disappears and $j,k$ are both in $\mathbb Z$.

Is it possible to obtain an expansion of Gaussian white noise $Z(t)$ and Brownian motion $B(t)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ in the basis (2) as done by Meyer, Sellan, and Taqqu by simply replacing the system (1) with the system (2)? E.g. following Eq. (2.4) in the paper by Meyer, Sellan, and Taqqu:
$$Z(t)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{j / 2} h\left(2^j t-k\right) \epsilon_{j, k}$$
where $\epsilon_{j, k}, j, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Both systems of functions from (1) and (2), respectively, are orthonormal bases of $L^2$. And doesn't a linear combination of an orthonormal basis with standard normal random coefficients always give white noise?

Comment: @Dirk: thank you, Intuitively I was convinced of it but I thought it had to be formally demonstrated.